# Register to Addressbook changes, using ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications, abaddressbook

I really need some help here.

I do exactly the same as in all the examples, but don't get any notification.

Here's my code:

```
 #import <AddressBook/ABAddressBook.h>
 #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

**Registering for notification:**

```
ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(book, addressBookChanged, self);
```

**Definition of the callback:**

```
void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef reference, 
                        CFDictionaryRef dictionary, 
                        void *context) 
{

   ViewController *viewController = (ViewController*)context;
   [viewController addressBookChanged];    
}
```

**And another method:**

```
-(void) addressBookChanged
{
   NSLog(@"%@", @"addressBookChanged");
}
```

- I'm running the app
- Switching to the contacts app
- Adding a new contact
- nothing happens... no log, nothing...

What am I doing wrong here?

- Any ' #import ' missing?
- Should it work on device/simulator?
- Any specific way of declaring the callback? Static maybe?

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I know the answer now...

The callback is being invoked, **but only when I resume back my application**.

Comment: Did you get any information about newly added or edited contact in Addressbook?

Comment: I mean, the notification is general, not containing any info about the changed AB entry.

Comment: @Gal Exactly where do you need to keep this code? I'm having many files and created a separate file called contact and in contact.m I first created addressbook and in the permission grant block wrote the register external callback. In the same file I wrote the function addressBookChanged. Is it compulsory to write the function code in AppDelegate or somewhere else specific.

Comment: @Gal
But when i added code to register call backs Using ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(book, addressBookChanged, self);
Xcode Asking me to cast self to (__bridge void *)(self) like this
but when i allowed it to cast,im getting CFDictionaryRef dictionary parameter with nil value even i updated a contact .....
thanks in Advance..help me out

Comment: @Naresh Reddy M , is your `ABAddressBookRef` global?

Comment: @Gal nope its a local object only :)